# chkconfig shows off in all levels but it running

Tags: centos6, httpd, lamp, daemon, chkconfig

In my CentOS6 machine, `chkconfig` shows about `httpd` as below, but running automatically whenever reboot the system.

```
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

What can I check more to know which init logic make it?

Note that my colleague installed lampp in `/opt/lampp` directory and `ps aux` shows as below.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
daemon    2159  0.0  0.3 432752  5368 ?        S    01:57   0:00 /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -D
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking at `/etc/inittab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ sudo grep -ri lampp /etc` should show you what did it. Maybe /etc/rc.local or some other cruddy init script.

Comment: It shows 
`/etc/rc3.d/S99local:/opt/lampp/lampp start, /etc/rc.local:/opt/lampp/lampp start, /etc/rc2.d/S99local:/opt/lampp/lampp start` got it. thanks